# How do I write a program which takes two objects and combine each other?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var fbAcc = {
    "apurba" : "aapurba9",
    "reejan" : "hreejan",
    "kiran" : "kiran901"

};
var redAcc = {
    "apurba" : "phantom9",
    "reejan" : "reejanbroo",
    "suyog" : "seaten69"
};

function combineObj(a, b){

}
combineObj(fbAcc, redAcc);


//Output :
//{
//"apurba" : ["aapurba9", "phantom9"],
//"reejan" : ["hreejan", "reejanbroo"],
//"kiran" : ["kiran901"],
//"suyog" : ["seaten"]
//}
```

I want my combineObj function to technically combine the object on the basis of the key or the string before : . In this case I want it to return how I wrote it in output.
So how can I do it?

Comment: How about the spread operator? `{ ...fbAcc, ...redAcc }`. If you need to make it a function - go for it, but there's no real need in having it separately because it can be achieved with an operator.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You can first take entries of the object and then just `reduce` it.

```js
var fbAcc = { "apurba" : "aapurba9", "reejan" : "hreejan", "kiran" : "kiran901"};
var redAcc = { "apurba" : "phantom9", "reejan" : "reejanbroo", "suyog" : "seaten69"};

var k=[...Object.entries(fbAcc ), ...Object.entries(redAcc)];

var result = k.reduce((acc, [k,v])=>{
   acc[k] =acc[k] || [];
   acc[k].push(v);
   return acc;
},{});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function combineObj(a, b) {
    let res = {};
    for (const key in a) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            res[key] = [a[key]];
            if (b.hasOwnProperty(key) && b[key] !== a[key]) {
                res[key].push(b[key]);                
            }           
        }
    }
    for (const key in b) {
        if (b.hasOwnProperty(key) && !res.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            res[key] = [b[key]];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```